# How to prevent constrained text from disappearing after too many characters?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, text-wrap

I am trying to get a long string of 1's and 0's to line break within a simple rectangular path created in Photoshop CS6 (Extended 13.0.1 64Bit).  However, when I reach an unknown number of characters ALL of them disappear!  Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong?

Steps to recreate:

1. Create a new canvas 600px X 600px
2. Put any picture in there as a new BG layer (not sure if this is required)
3. Create a rectangular path over the entire image
4. Change your font to 8px Fixedsys (or other mono-spaced font, i.e. Consolas)
5. Paste a ton of 1's and 0's with NO line-breaks in it - OR - if you want to actually see it happen, type out a couple of lines of 1's & 0's then copy and paste those until they all magically disappear!

Why is this happening and what can I do about it?

**Edit: I just checked and the magic number it's pooping out on is 3613.**

Comment: If I lower the font size I can add even more characters..  But the same thing occurs - it all disappears before I can fill the entire path with text.

Answer (score 1):

When a line of text can not be wrapped to fit it's container, it disappears.

Either add spaces, line breaks, or use point text. Or use a clipping mask rather than constrained text.

Comment: Couldn´t you add a *discretionary line break* between every char for this effect to work?

Comment: I don't believe Photoshop supports discretionary line breaks. I could be incorrect though.

Comment: probably it does only if you copy form indesign